# Google Secret Manager secrets not loaded into application properties - Spring Boot - App Engine

Tags: spring-boot, google-secret-manager

I have a spring boot project deployed on App Engine (war)

application.properties

```
mysecret=${sm://projects/48***1430/secrets/order-db-password}
```

In controller, I am using a value annotation

```
@Value("${mysecret}")
private String myAppSecret;
```

Log is printing -

> "myAppSecret   = //projects/48***1430/secrets/order-db-password"

build.gradle

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:1.2.2.RELEASE'
```

permissions seems ok

```
myapplication@appspot.gserviceaccount.com is Secret manager admin
```

How can I identify the problem?

Comment: Do you have this dependency?
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: I use gradle and it is included. I added that line in my question. Why I don't see any error? It is just removing "sm:"and printing the rest

Answer (score 6):

I needed 3 changes

i)bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.bootstrap.enabled=true
```

ii)dependency - otherwise won't look at bootstrap.props

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

For secret manager

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager'
```

iii) use secret - long or short, but I am using full format

```
spring.datasource.password=${sm://projects/4#6##4#0/secrets/dbencpwd}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you move that assignment

```
mysecret=${sm://projects/48***1430/secrets/order-db-password}
```

to bootstrap.properties file (if you don't have it, create it in resources dir)

Some issues were reported while reading gcp configuration properties from application.properties

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/252

Comment: Thanks. I thought bootstrap is not for placeholders.  will check.